# How to update a template with random numbers values

Tags: python, html, flask

I have the below posted template. What I want to do is, to update the rendered template with the random values generated. In other words, I want to call the web-service once and I want to see the random numbers is generated on the below posted template.

Please have a look at the python code and the .html code and let me know how to achieve that.

**index.html**:

```
<body>
<p> {{ random_number }} is your random number. </p>
</body>
```

**python code**:

```
@app.route("/getRandomNumbers", methods=['GET'] )
def getRandomNumbers():
random_number = random.random()
return render_template('index.html', random_number=random_number)
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your issue, the next codes work.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask Template Example</title>
</head>
<body>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    a=random.random()
    return render_template("index.html", message=str(a))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```